# Correcting linear regression for change in air temperature over time

Tags: regression, time-series, experiment-design, spatial, meteorology

Say I collect temperature data over 5 square kilometers over the course of an hour in the evening but I want to analyze the data as though they were collected all at the same time. Naturally the area will cool so my assumption that the data was collected at the same time is inaccurate. If I wanted to analyze subtle temperature variability patterns across the AOI (area of interest) natural cooling will influence my results. Is there a method like a correction factor or model or otherwise I could use to negate the natural cooling of the earth? Is there any way to avoid the assumption that the earth maintains a static temperature?

Bear in mind:

- There is only one thermometer and I'm trying to cover as much ground as possible over 1 hour to get as many data points as I can.
- Data can only be collected on a single day.
- We do have access to other variables (elevation, land use, regional temperature, etc.).
- Data have already been collected and we cannot go back to do more collecting (although we could change collection protocols from here on out!)
- There are some other data sources to use for a potential model to compare to or to potentially create a regional curve for temperature change over the course of that hour.

Comment: Why don‘t you create a natural/average cooling temperature curve by yourself (by eyeballing/taking the mean/...) and then run a model (in fact, any model, not necessarily linear regression) on the differences between the actual value and the overall cooling curve? Of course the details depend on what you want to do: do you have temperature data from very different climate zones? Etc. another option would be to include time as a column that the model has access to but then you need to encode it as seconds after midnight or so...

Comment: Cover your area by different routes different evenings ...

Comment: @FabianWerner I like this thought process! Can you expand on what you mean by add "time as a column" but encode as seconds? I have done so, but I'm not sure I follow what you mean about how this would influence the model.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I agree this is the best solution! For the purpose of this question (or as a thought experiment) the data have already been collected and I am unable to return to the site(s) to collect more data. I have to work with what I have. However - I can use publicly available datasets to help explore/model the data!

Comment: Can you add this to the Q as an edit? Not everybody reads comments ... and some more details about the data, are there multiple days with measurements? Do you have map information? elevations? Possibility for some prior map based on meteorology?